# Why the following code doesn't compile?

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
   private:
      int i;
   public:
      void f1(const A& o);
      void f2()
      {
         cout<<i<<endl;
      }
};

void A::f1(const A& o)
{
   o.f2();
}
```

It just doesn't compile. Can somebody give a explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: Most likely there is a error message from the compiler or the linker that tells you why. And you should provide it to make it easy to locate the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably, your compiler told you why it doesn't compile. Mine said:

```
In member function ‘void A::f1(const A&)’:
passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void A::f2()’ discards qualifiers
```

This tells me that you're trying to call a non-`const` member function (`A::f2`) on a reference to a `const` object (`const A& o`).

Either add a `const` qualifier to the function to allow it to be called on `const` objects:

```
void f2() const
          ^^^^^
```

or remove `const` from the reference to allow modification - but in this case, don't do that, since `f2()` doesn't need to modify the object.

Answer (score 6):

`A::f2()` needs to be declared `const` to be used from your `const` reference.

Change:

```
void f2()
```

to:

```
void f2() const
```

You cannot call non-`const` functions on a `const` object. By declaring the function as `const` you are guaranteeing that it doesn't change the state of the object (with the exception of `mutable` member variables).